# Does anyone know what these letters mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, character-identification, seal

I have seen these letters written in a particular way and I would like to know their meaning.
I don't know if they are in the correct position so I sent 2 possible positions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any context? I would usually imagine that some choice users would be quick to answer this type of question but it seems like some additional information may be needed first this time.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is two months late; I hope you still need the information.

The position in your first image seems right. I still can't figure out what the first character is, but the second character is quite undoubtedly 妙 ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A6%99)) in a kind of seal script (篆书), though it looks a bit wonky.

Variation of character forms in seal scripts can be considerable, but I have an example for you - you can see it in the top right corner of this seal:

[image: "妙吉羊菴" by San'geng Xu (徐三庚)]

["妙吉羊菴" by San'geng Xu (徐三庚)]

The left halves of them aren't exactly the same (one more stroke in the image you provide), but I'm inclined to think that's due to a misinterpretation of one long stroke as two separate strokes.